# VSCode DJLint extension formats python files

Tags: django, django-templates, vscode-extensions

My DJLint extension for VSCode recognizes problems in python files however it is not supposed to. It is supposed to run only in html files.
[DJLint error in python File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crike.png)

Now my settings tell me that this extension is only running in the default file formats that do not include `.py` [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h65kz.png).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and it was driving me crazy. Turns out, it was caused by changing the  VSCode setting `djlint.enableLinting` to `true` for anything other than the specific languages you wanted to lint. For example, if you turned it on for the workspace or the user, it will lint all the files in the workspace. To fix this, just turn the setting off in your User or Workspace settings.